# amdgpu: Unsupported power profile mode 0

Tags: boot, amdgpu

I shutdown my computer today to try to boot it back up. I am getting the message: `[6.043685] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: Unsupported power profile mode 0 on RENOIR` on a black screen. **What is this and can I fix it?**

Comment: seems to be a bug (apparently now fixed in newer versions of the Kernel) see [this reference](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211799) and [this one](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/T14-AMD-battery-drain-in-standby-Linux/m-p/5037674?page=31#5336709)

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a different issue, I found a workaround. Try using the `modesetting` driver for the AMD gpu. This can be done by creating a file */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf* with the following content:

```
# To workaround bug https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355957/amdgpu-unsupported-power-profile-mode-0
Section "Device"
     Identifier "AMD"
     Driver "modesetting"
EndSection
```

Let me know if it works. For debugging, post the output of the command **inxi -G**

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] driver: nvidia v: 470.57.02 
       Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Renoir driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
       Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: modesetting tty: N/A 
       OpenGL: renderer: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.40.0 5.11.0-25-lowlatency LLVM 12.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3
```

**Note**:My system has dual graphics and I have enabled backports so the output may be a little different; the main thing is that the X11 driver should be `modesetting`.

Comment: Is it not so that the modesetting driver will disable all on-GPU acceleration for 3d?

Comment: @eudoxos nope games etc still ran fine with the modesetting driver. The default amdgpu driver started working for me again around 3 weeks ago, so the workaround may not be necessary now.

Answer (score 0):

## A WORKAROUND

*Disclaimer: IT DID WORK ON MY MACHINE: Linux Xubuntu 20.04 this does not mean this is the proper solution, or even a "solver", but, rather a by-passer so to speak.*

*My pc specifications:*

- **Motherboard: ASUS, B450M**
- **Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5700G, 8-Core, 16-Threads, 3.8GHz (4.6GHz Turbo),** **Cache 20MB, AM4, 100-100000263BOX**
- **RAM: Team Group T-Force Dark Z 32GB (2x16) DDR4 3600MHz RED, TDZRD432G3600HC18JDC01**

*My problems ended when I tried formating my pc to Linux Xubuntu 20.04, using a bootable flash drive. The boot menu showed up, I ctrl + alt + del out of it and the pc got back to normal.*